# QB64 Printer controls

Tags: printing

I'm using QB64, and I need to set font size, line spacing, and other printer controls.  According to the built in "help" on QB64, printer control codes used in QBasic don't work.  Any ideas?

I tried QBasic printer control codes that generally start with chr$(27) which is the esc, and did not work.